# Mongoid attr_accessible not working

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, attr-accessible

Today morning I wake with this weird issue where mongoid was creating  a record for the attributes which isn't being defined in the model

To overcome this i decide to implement attr_accessible also mention in Mongoid [specification](http://mongoid.org/docs/documents/access.html)

> "Providing a list of fields as accessible is simply the inverse of
>   protecting them. **Anything not defined as accessible will cause the
>   error**." -- Mongoid Specification

Think all would work fine I create a dummy record and too my surprise I got inserted as oppose to the statement above that

> "**Anything not defined as accessible will cause the error**

Here my model structure

```
class PartPriceRecord 
  include Mongoid::Document
    field :supplier_id,type: Integer
    field :part_number,type: String
    field :part_description, type: String
    field :core_indicator,type: String
    field :us_part_price,type: Float
    field :us_core_price,type: Float
    field :us_fleet_price,type: Float
    field :us_distributor_price,type: Float
    field :ca_part_price,type: Float
    field :ca_distributor_price,type: Float
    field :ca_core_price,type: Float
    field :ca_fleet_price,type: Float 
    field :basic_file_id,type: Integer
    index :part_number, unique: true

  validates_presence_of :supplier_id
  validates_presence_of :part_number
  #validates_uniqueness_of :part_number
  validates :part_number ,:format => { :with => /^[a-z0-9A-Z\s*-]+[-a-z0-9\s-]*[a-z0-9\s*-]+$/i ,:message => "Only AlphaNumeric Allowed" }
  validates :supplier_id, :format => { :with => /^[a-z0-9]+[-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9]+$/i , :message => "Only Alphanumeric Allowed" } 
  #validates :part_description,:presence => true

  validates :part_description,:format => { :with => /^[a-z0-9]+[-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9]+$/i ,:message => "Only Alphanumberic Allowed"} ,:allow_nil => true
  validates :core_indicator ,:inclusion => { :in => %w(Y N),
    :message => "%{value} is not a valid Coreindicator must be Y | N" 
   } ,:allow_nil => true,:allow_blank => true


 validates :us_part_price,:us_core_price,:us_fleet_price,:us_distributor_price,:ca_part_price,:ca_core_price,:ca_fleet_price,:ca_distributor_price ,:format => { :with => /^([0-9]+(\.([0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1}))?)$/ ,:message => "should look like money" } ,:allow_nil => true,:allow_blank => true

  @@required_attributes =[:supplier_id,:part_number,:part_description,:core_indicator,:us_part_price,:us_core_price,:us_fleet_price,:us_distributor_price,:ca_part_price,:ca_core_price,:ca_fleet_price,:ca_distributor_price]
  @@not_required_attributes = ["_id","basic_file_id"]  
  cattr_reader :required_attributes,:not_required_attributes
  attr_accessible :supplier_id,:part_number,:part_description, :core_indicator,:us_part_price,:us_core_price,:us_fleet_price,:us_distributor_price,:ca_part_price,:ca_distributor_price,:ca_core_price,:ca_fleet_price,:basic_file_id
end
```

and Here the record I creating from my console

```
ruby-1.9.2-head :003 > PartPriceRecord.count()
 => 260317 ## initial count before creating a new record
ruby-1.9.2-head :004 > p1 = PartPriceRecord.new(:customer_id => "One",:part_number => "ASA",:supplier_id => "Supp")
 => #<PartPriceRecord _id: 4fa77921d2d8d60e39000002, _type: nil, supplier_id: "Supp", part_number: "ASA", part_description: nil, core_indicator: nil, us_part_price: nil, us_core_price: nil, us_fleet_price: nil, us_distributor_price: nil, ca_part_price: nil, ca_distributor_price: nil, ca_core_price: nil, ca_fleet_price: nil, basic_file_id: nil> 
ruby-1.9.2-head :005 > p1.save
 => true  ## Record got created
ruby-1.9.2-head :006 > PartPriceRecord.count()
 => 260318  ## Count indicating record was created
```

Any idea why is this so ?

Thanks

Comment: So, what's wrong with that record?

Comment: @Sergio customer_id attributes is not define in attr_accessible

Comment: And it's not listed in the fields, why?

Comment: See this: http://mongoid.org/docs/documents/dynamic.html

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Are you sure this work cuz providing the allow_dynamic_fields to false in configuration options does not seem to work for me though record still getting created

Comment: Did you reload console after changing config (just checking)?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev .Yup started a exited the old and  loaded new console to check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is valid -- it appears that the documentation is inconsistent, not fully correct, and somewhat outdated, from the following tests and cursory reading of Mogoid code.

Fields that are attr_protected or NOT attr_accessible ignore mass assignment; they do NOT raise an error on mass assignment.

In the section on Protected, "raising an error" is incorrect, and the documentation even mismatches User and Person.  In the section on Accessible, "will cause the error" is incorrect, but the comment "silently ignore protected ones" gives a clue that no error is raised and that the mass assignment is ignored.

Here's a fragment from mongoid/spec/mongoid/attributes_spec.rb that supports this.

```
describe ".attr_accessible" do

  context "when the field is not _id" do

    let(:account) do
      Account.new(number: 999999)
    end

    it "prevents setting via mass assignment" do
      account.number.should be_nil
    end
  end
...
end
```

You must add the field customer_id to your PartPriceRecord model.  My tests for User and PartPriceRecord follow.  Hope that this helps.

```
require 'test_helper'

class PartPriceRecordTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    User.delete_all
    PartPriceRecord.delete_all
  end

  test "User" do
    assert_equal(0, User.count())
    # Set attributes on a user properly.
    user = User.new(first_name: "Corbin")
    assert_equal("Corbin", user.first_name)
    user.attributes = { first_name: "Corbin" }
    assert_equal("Corbin", user.first_name)
    user.write_attributes(first_name: "Corbin")
    assert_equal("Corbin", user.first_name)

    # Attempt to set attributes a user, raising an error. # <-- This documentation is incorrect, no error is raised
    #user = User.new(first_name: "Corbin", password: "password")
    user.attributes = { first_name: "Corbin", password: "password" } # inaccessible field is forced to nil
    assert_equal("Corbin", user.first_name)
    assert_equal(nil, user.password)
    user.write_attributes(first_name: "Corbin", password: "password") # inaccessible field is forced to nil
    assert_equal("Corbin", user.first_name)
    assert_equal(nil, user.password)
  end

  test "PartPriceRecord" do
    assert_equal(0, PartPriceRecord.count())
    p1 = PartPriceRecord.new(:customer_id => "One",:part_number => "ASA",:supplier_id => "Supp")
    assert_equal(nil, p1.customer_id)
    p1.save
    assert_equal(1, PartPriceRecord.count())
    assert_equal(nil, PartPriceRecord.find(p1.id).customer_id)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks I guess that what I was looking for but adding a customer_id to PartPriceRecord is what I can't do as customer_id is an just a one key that can be present when I'm parsing a CSV so at any time the CSV can have any field that doesnot belongs to PartPriceRecord prevent that is what is was looking through attr_accessible